# How to make pandas read empty data file as an empty dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, emptydatatext

We can assign an empty dataframe with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
zero = pd.DataFrame()
zero
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

The `zero` dataframe is empty containing nothing in it,create a empty data file containing nothing in it.

```
fh = open('/tmp/test.txt','w')
fh.close()
```

The file `/tmp/test.txt` is empty.

```
newzero = pd.read_csv('/tmp/test.txt',header=None)
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

How to make pandas read an empty file and assign it as a empty dataframe such as `zero` shows ?
Is there a way to add some argument to make the below commands running without error info.

```
newzero = pd.read_csv('/tmp/test.txt',header=None,add some argument)
newzero
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch exception and create a empty data frame

```
import pandas as pd
zero = pd.DataFrame()
fh = open('/tmp/test.txt','r')
fh.close()
try:
    newzero = pd.read_csv('test.txt',header=None)
except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
    newzero = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: Please format your code with just four blank at the beginning of the indent line.

Comment: Right. I did :)

Comment: Maybe it is better to set the two variables `nozero` and `newzero` as one `newzero`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the straightforward way of doing it :

```
import pandas as pd
fh = open('/tmp/test.txt','w')
fh.close()

try:
    newzero = pd.read_csv('/tmp/test.txt',header=None)
except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
    new_zero = pd.DataFrame()
```